# Getting common keys from different dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have two dictionaries (in my program there are more than two):

```
a={'ab':3, 'bc':4, 'cj':2}
b={'ab':2, 'cd':2, 'ed':2, 'cj':4}
```

and want to get the common keys between them:

```
common_keys=['ab','cj']
```

what should I do?

I understand `set.intersection` but do not know how to turn the dictionary keys into a set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use dictionary views with [`dict.viewkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys) and set operations:

```
common_keys = a.viewkeys() & b.viewkeys() & c.viewkeys()
```

If you are using Python 3 instead, the [`dict.keys()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) returns a dictionary view already:

```
common_keys = a.keys() & b.keys() & c.keys()
```

Either operation returns a [`set` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

Demo:

```
>>> a = {'ab': 3, 'bc': 4, 'cj': 2}
>>> b = {'ab': 2, 'cd': 2, 'ed': 2, 'cj': 4}
>>> c = {'ab': 6, 'ad': 2, 'dd': 2, 'cj': 1}
>>> a.viewkeys() & b.viewkeys() & c.viewkeys()
set(['cj', 'ab'])
```

Comment: why is using sets faster than using viewkeys?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: are sets faster than viewkeys?

Comment: Using the OP's the code, `viewkeys -> 1.15 µs per loop`,`set(a).intersection... -> 706 ns per loop
`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: on 2.7 I do see a speed difference too; not sure why. Not big enough to forgo the clarity though.

Comment: Yep,not a major difference I just presumed using `viewkeys` would be faster.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: creating the view is a *lot* faster than creating the set, but the intersection ops are slower. Possibly an optimisation used in sets is missing in view objects.